# How to use all possible resources on all nodes to generate Hfiles using MapReduce in Hadoop?

Tags: database, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hbase

I have a fully distributed three node Hadoop cluster (1 namenode and 2 datanodes) with fully distributed Hbase (1 active master, 1 backup masters, 2 servers, 0 dead, 5.0000 average load). I want to generate Hfiles in the fastest possible way. I load Hfiles to Hbase using `rg.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles`. Each cluster has 40 cores so I run in parallel 40 processes. My problem is that only the server with Hmaster and Namenode uses something around 97% of CPU and almost all RAM. On the other two servers the resources are almost not used at all. My question is whether is it possible to improve performance using also them during generating Hfiles? Furthemore, maybe there is a feature in MapReduce to configure how many cores and nodes I want to use instead of writing python program which is shown below and which I use at the moment? Thanks in advance.

```
import subprocess
import os
import time

processes = set()
max_processes = 40

for key in range(0,40):

    time.sleep(1)
    command = 'sudo -u hdfs /path/to/hbase/bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.separator="," -Dimporttsv.bulk.output=hdfs://myip:9000/tmp/converted_10m' + str(key) + ' -Dimporttsv.columns="HBASE_ROW_KEY,log" logs hdfs://myip:9000/tmp/10m_package' + str(key) + '.csv'
    processes.add(subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True))
    if len(processes) >= max_processes:
        os.wait()
        processes.difference_update([
            p for p in processes if p.poll() is not None])
```

Comment: Are you running NodeManagers on all the hosts?

Comment: @tk421 Sorry for such a late response, however I didn't notice notification. JPS shows that NodeManagers are running on all three nodes. Do you have any ideas how to improve performance?